# Shared folder is locked Dropbox

Tags: dropbox, phpstorm, shared-directory, locked-files

I'm using Dropbox and I've just tried to share folder with my PHPStorm project to another team mate by `Invite to folder option`. And after them PHPStorm writes me this: `Could not save project!: Unable to save project files. Please ensure project files are writable and you have permissions to modify them.`
And I cannot find how to get out of this.

Have you some experience about this?